# Counting number of changes in categorical column in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I have a PySpark dataframe that looks like this:

```py
data = [(2010, 3, 12, 0, 'p1', 'state1'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 0, 'p2', 'state2'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 0, 'p3', 'state1'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 0, 'p4', 'state2'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 2, 'p1', 'state3'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 2, 'p2', 'state1'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 2, 'p3', 'state3'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 4, 'p1', 'state1'), 
         (2010, 3, 12, 6, 'p1', 'state1')]

columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'process_id','state']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
df.show()
```

```
+----+-----+---+----+----------+------+
|year|month|day|hour|process_id| state|
+----+-----+---+----+----------+------+
|2010|    3| 12|   0|        p1|state1|
|2010|    3| 12|   0|        p2|state2|
|2010|    3| 12|   0|        p3|state1|
|2010|    3| 12|   0|        p4|state2|
|2010|    3| 12|   2|        p1|state3|
|2010|    3| 12|   2|        p2|state1|
|2010|    3| 12|   2|        p3|state3|
|2010|    3| 12|   4|        p1|state1|
|2010|    3| 12|   6|        p1|state1|
+----+-----+---+----+----------+------+
```

The dataframe is already sorted in an increasing order by the four columns: `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour` as above. The increment is in 2-hour interval.

I would like to find out, for each `process_id`, how many times its state changes within each `day`. For that, I intend to use `groupby`, something like this:

```py
chg_count_df = df.groupby('process_id', 'year', 'month', 'day').
               agg(.....)
```

For this example, the expected output is:

```
+----+-----+---+----------+----------+
|year|month|day|process_id| chg_count|
+----+-----+---+----------+----------+
|2010|    3| 12|        p1|         2|
|2010|    3| 12|        p2|         1|
|2010|    3| 12|        p3|         1|
|2010|    3| 12|        p4|         0|
+----+-----+---+----------+----------+
```

What should go into the `agg(...)` function? Or is there a better to way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could employ [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) window function to check if a state was changed. Then `groupBy` using `sum`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
w = W.partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day', 'process_id').orderBy(F.desc('hour'))
df = df.withColumn('change', F.coalesce((F.lag('state').over(w) != F.col('state')).cast('int'), F.lit(0)))
df = df.groupBy('year', 'month', 'day', 'process_id').agg(F.sum('change').alias('chg_count'))

df.show()
# +----+-----+---+----------+---------+
# |year|month|day|process_id|chg_count|
# +----+-----+---+----------+---------+
# |2010|    3| 12|        p1|        2|
# |2010|    3| 12|        p2|        1|
# |2010|    3| 12|        p3|        1|
# |2010|    3| 12|        p4|        0|
# +----+-----+---+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chg_count_df = df.groupby('process_id', 'year', 'month', 'day').count()
```

Comment: Process ```p1``` has ```count``` of 4, but there are only 2 changes within the day.